# Exception while Dropbox API tries to read a resource - might be multidex issue?

Tags: android, dropbox, android-multidex

I have an Android app with Dropbox support. Lately I've started getting an exception for some users. I can not reproduce it. It affects just a few users. The exception happens when Dropbox tries to access `/sdk-version.txt` which is one of their resources. On Android Studio I can see the resource is there, here is a screenshot:

[image]

And like I said, it doesn't happen for me or for most of my users. If I use apktool on my apk, the `sdk-version.txt` file shows up on a folder called `unknown`. I see a lot of other files there but most have a package, this one doesn't. Not sure if that matters.

I also have this line on my gradle file `multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')` and in there I have:

```
com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil
com.dropbox.core.http.HttpRequestor
com.dropbox.core.DbxSdkVersion
```

Those were all attempts at fixing this but it didn't help.

So far the exception has happened on Android 5 and 6 across multiple manufacturers. This is the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.buildUserAgentHeader(DbxRequestUtil.java:151)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.addUserAgentHeader(DbxRequestUtil.java:136)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:233)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:107)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:284)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:102)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.users.DbxUserUsersRequests.getCurrentAccount(DbxUserUsersRequests.java:120)
       at mypackage.UserDropbox.(UserDropbox.java)
       at mypackage.DropboxHelper$1.run(DropboxHelper.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:81smiling face with sunglasses
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.jar.JarVerifier.removeMetaEntries()' on a null object reference
       at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:381)
       at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:222)
       at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:444)
       at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:1412)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxSdkVersion.loadLineFromResource(DbxSdkVersion.java:34)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxSdkVersion.loadVersion(DbxSdkVersion.java:56)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxSdkVersion.(DbxSdkVersion.java)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.buildUserAgentHeader(DbxRequestUtil.java:151)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.addUserAgentHeader(DbxRequestUtil.java:136)
       at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:233)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:107)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:284)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:102)
       at com.dropbox.core.v2.users.DbxUserUsersRequests.getCurrentAccount(DbxUserUsersRequests.java:120)
       at mypackage.UserDropbox.(UserDropbox.java)
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/java-lang-ExceptionInInitializerError/m-p/253612 ]

Comment: That's mine as well.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't a direct solution**.

You can integrate [fabric clashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) into your app to get a full report on the cause of the exception and information on the type and OS of devices experiencing the Exception.

Comment: That is how I'm getting the crash report. I haven't really seen a pattern on devices reporting it. I have it on Android 5 and 6, Motorola and Samsung but I only have this in beta so I have very few reports.